# How to pass parameter to my event handling code for printing image

Tags: c#, printing, event-handling

I am using the below code to print an image from my C# code. Can some body tell me how to pass the filePath as an argument when i assign my event handler ?

```
  public static bool PrintImage(string filePath)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printPage);
        pd.Print();
        return true;

    }
    private static void printPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //i want to receive the file path as a paramter here.

        Image i = Image.FromFile("C:\\Zapotec.bmp");
        Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a lambda expression:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) => DrawImage(filePath, args.Graphics);
pd.Print();

...

private static void DrawImage(string filePath, Graphics graphics)
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you've not got a lot to do, you could even inline the whole thing:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) => 
{
    Image i = Image.FromFile(filePath);
    Point p = new Point(100, 100);
    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
};
pd.Print();
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is use an anonymous function as the event handler.  This will allow you to pass the `filePath` directly

```
public static bool PrintImage(string filePath) {
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += delegate (sender, e) { printPage(filePath, e); };
  pd.Print();
  return true;
}

private static void printPage(string filePath, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared. But as you see, my printPage method making use of the argument e. How to handle that ?

Comment: @Happy completely missed that. updated my answer to pass it along as well

Comment: where is `sender` coming from ?

Comment: @Happy sender is whatever the `PrintPage` event code passed as the sender argument to the event. It wasn't used in the event handler so I didn't pass it along.  It could be easily passed though in the same manner that `e` was passed

Comment: Thanks. +1 for sure for the helping mentality.